# Perfect tense - where should one use "haben" and "sein"?

Tags: perfect-tense, past-participle

Can

> Wir sind im Meer geschwommen

be written as

> Wir haben im Meer geschwommen

and

> Wir haben Musik gehört

as

> Wir sind Musik gehört

I am not understanding where to use *haben* and where to use *sein*.