# sein or haben in "Nachdem sie auf Lanzarote angekommen waren, mieteten sie ein Auto und fuhren ans Meer."

Tags: pluperfect

I have the sentence

> Nachdem sie auf Lanzarote angekommen waren, mieteten sie ein Auto und fuhren ans Meer.

and I was left slightly confused.

I would have thought that the pl. past conjugation of **haben** would have been correct rather than **waren** i.e.

> Nachdem sie auf Lanzarote angekommen **hatten**, mieteten sie ein Auto und fuhren ans Meer.

Is there a reason for not using hatten over waren?

Comment: _"Is there a reason for not using hate over haben?"_ Why should _haben_ be relevant for this sentence at all? I don't understand your question? And what do you mean with _hate_ please?

Comment: Look at the several conjugations of _sein_, these are different from the stem _haben_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ apologies mistake was due to autocorrect - now fixed.

Comment: @DavidSmith Take a look and see whether [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48537/perfect-tense-where-should-one-use-haben-and-sein) helps you.

Comment: A medium-sized group of German verbs use *sein* as their perfect tenses auxiliary instead of *haben*. A good dictionary always tells you that oddity for a verb.

Answer (score 4):

With most verbs one uses *haben* as auxiliary verb to form the perfect (or Plusquamperfekt), but with some, *sein* must be used.

Verbs of movement generally use *sein* for the perfect. This includes *kommen* and its derivatives, including *ankommen*. Because of this,

> Sie waren angekommen

is correct, and *Sie hatten angekommen* is wrong.